# Incompatible types String and Date in Einstein filter

Tags: einstein-analytics

I am trying to apply a filter

`Date_Received>= toDate(date_to_epoch(now())-(31556926))`

in filter transformation in Einstein dataflow.

***toDate(date_to_epoch(now())-(31556926))*** is giving the expected output

> 2018-12-31 06:03:36

But I am getting the below error while executing dataflow:

> Something went wrong while executing the filter:Date_Received_one_year
>   node: Incompatible types: STRING and DATE in 'Date_Received' >=
>   |2018-12-31 06:03:36 (02K0r0000009ZcIEAU_03C0r000000HMRSEA4)

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Based on the error, it sounds like "Date_Received" is a string whereas the other half of the compare is a date. If you add toDate(Date_Received) to the beginning does it work?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a function within a filter Transformation.

To achieve that, you have to use a computeExpression and generate a new field (for example dateFilter -> toDate(date_to_epoch(now())-(31556926)) )
Then use that dateFilter Field to filter out rows. I have struggled with that many times. Some error texts in Salesforce are pretty misleading IMHO

After the filter you can slice that field if you don't need it anymore.